# Normality assumption in neural networks with linear output layer

Tags: neural-networks, normal-distribution, assumptions

I'm learning about neural network from the [Deep learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) In chapter 6.2.2.1 they say Linear output layer are often used to produce the mean of a conditional Gaussian distribution:

$p(y|x) = \mathcal{N}(y;\hat{y},I)$ (Equation 6.17)

I don't know how can we make this assumption, is there any mathematical theory or proof about this? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: How is this related to regression? The book is about neural networks and the section you are citing does not mention regression. So I have edited your tags and title accordingly. However, feel free to undo the edit if you believe a clear relation to regression exists.

Comment: @RichardHardy It should be linear-regression. That's my mistake

Comment: How is this related to linear regression then? True, sometimes normality is assumed in a linear regression model, but that is neither necessary nor sufficient to establish the connection; normality can be assumed in other models, and normality is not necessarily assumed in linear regression.

Comment: I was confused because I found this assumption is apply to Linear regression in another part from this book then there's no *regression tag needed. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @TrungLêHoàng I also had  a same question as you asked here. Can you please me tell me how you dealt with it if you did?